# Microsoft Bot Framework:task module

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am sending adaptive cards to teams and wanted to open a iframe on clicking a button in card using task module.Using hero cards iframe can be opened but when using adaptive cards iframe is not opened.

On getting task invoke I am sending

```
 {
    task: {
      type: 'continue',
      value: {
        title: 'Iframe',
        height: 400,
        width: 500,
        url,
        fallbackUrl: url
      }
    }
  };
```

the above object as response

I am using Action.Submit for adaptive cards

Comment: Have you tested the above card in https://adaptivecards.io/ and see if it works? This will help you to isolate the issue outside of iframe as well.

Comment: Does the above helped?

Comment: No, when i clicked on button loading animation is shown but pop up is not opened
Working fine with adaptive cards though

Comment: Hi @Nithin,

Could you please have a look on this [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module). Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Nithin, did you try the Teams task module sample as mentioned above?

Comment: It woked.You need to add an additional property to the adaptive card.You can get more info in this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-cards-actions